# Помогите оценить время работы функции

Tags: java, runtime

помогите рассчитать (формально) время работы функции :

```
for (i=n;i >= 3; i-- {
     for (j=1;j < ln(i) ;j++) {
         for (k=0 ;k <= n; k +=j)
          z++
printIn (z)
```

Спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

Для оценки времени работы метода или еще чего используй такую конструкцию:

```
    System.out.println("Starting: ");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Здесь какой-то код

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time take: " + (end - start));
```